# Innobackupex apply-log should be done before emergency restore or after each backup?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona, backup, xtradb-cluster, xtrabackup

Basically Percona Innobackupex consist with three steps:
1. Backup
2. Apply log
3. Copy back restore during emergency

My question:
When should I do apply log? Is it after each backup or before emergency restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the redo log right after a backup copy is taken you can greatly reduce time to restore.

Sometimes --apply-log step fails. Due to a bug or tablespace corruption. In either case you don't want to learn that in the emergency. That's one more argument to do the --apply-log after the backup.

People don't apply the redo log because it brings in more complexity to the backup process. For example, you cannot stream and apply the log.  If you take incremental backups the --apply-log makes it even more complex and you loose any intermediate recovery points (at best you'll have a state as of full backup time and the most current state. It may be OK though).

Comment: for my case, it make sense not apply log before emergency happen. May I know if it's possible to test apply-log each time after backup is done?

Comment: Well, you can take a copy of the backup, test the apply-log and trash it. This is something unusual though. Would you mind describing what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to ensure backup is not corrupted. After you said apply log might fail, I am little bit scare, so I want to know if it's possible to test apply log.

Comment: Then take a backup, apply the log and store it until you need it.
This way you'll be sure --apply-log succeeds and the restore time will decrease. When you need to restore just copy the backup copy to datadir, change ownership to mysql and you're ready to go.

Comment: but for incremental backup, I can't do apply log right?

Comment: You can but it's a bit tricky. You need to specify options --apply-log --redo-only on the full copy and all but the last incremental copies. The last incremental copy you should prepare w/o --redo-only. Please note when you apply an incremental copy on the full copy the state of the database moves to the point when the incremental copy was taken.

Comment: BTW, check out TwinDB online backups https://console.twindb.com. It's much easier than writing your own wrappers.

Comment: we don't have budget to spend on online backup yet. Can you give an example on howto steps to apply 3 incremental backup using innobackupex please?

Comment: What do you mean, no budget? It's free. I'll send the commands later when I get to a computer.

Comment: size below 2GB is free :)

Comment: I replied to similar question. Check it out http://serverfault.com/questions/578448/percona-xtrabackup-incremental-backup-based-on-prepared-full-backup

Comment: yes, we give 2G free. If you need more - you can add your own storage https://twindb.com/how-to-backup-mysql-to-your-own-storage-servers/
You can add as many storage servers as you need.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103761/innobackupex-restore-steps-from-1-incremental-and-multiple-incremental-steps