# Innobackupex restore steps from 1 incremental and multiple incremental steps

Tags: mysql, percona, backup, xtrabackup

My current backup plan is:
Full -> Incremental1 based on full -> incremental2 based on incremental1 -> incremental3 based on incremental2...

Please validate if this steps is correct during emergency restore:

to restore from 1 incremental backup:
innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only FULL-BACKUP-DIR
innobackupex --apply-log FULL-BACKUP-DIR --incremental-dir=INC-BACKUP-DIR1

to restore from multiple incremental backups:
innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only FULL-BACKUP-DIR
innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only BASE-DIR --incremental-dir=INCREMENTAL-DIR-1
innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only INCREMENTAL-DIR-1 --incremental-dir=INCREMENTAL-DIR-2
innobackupex --apply-log --redo-only INCREMENTAL-DIR-2 --incremental-dir=INCREMENTAL-DIR-3
.
.
innobackupex --apply-log FULL-BACKUP-DIR --incremental-dir=INCREMENTAL-DIR-LAST